# static in php behaves strangly, can't accept functions

Tags: php, php-5.3

This code throws parse error, which I do not understand why.

```
function t(){
 return 'g';
}
function l(){
    static $b = t();
    return $b;
}
l();
```

The question is, why?

Comment: As an aside if you declare `static $b; $b = t();` then `l()` properly returns 'g' as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static` variables values are filled on source parsing step, thus they cannot contain non-constant values.

You could implement the value initialization with something like:

```
function l(){
    static $b;
    if (!$b) $b = t();
    return $b;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Quoting from the manual:

> **Note:**
>
> Trying to assign values to these [static] variables **which are the
>   result of expressions** will cause a parse error.

(my emphasis)

c.f. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php Example #7